# How do I change a domain address variable with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, redirect

I need to be able to change a domain variable (or set it if it's not already set) and then reload the page. I do not care if the page doesn't reload in fact I need it to reload.

For example if a user is on page: sample.com/demo?theme=theme1
and they select a new theme from the dropdown I want to change the theme variable to navigate the browser to the same page with the new domain variable, so in this case sample.com/demo?theme=newtheme.

I can't just do a standard redirect because I don't want them just going to the homepage I want them to stay on the current page just have the variable changed. For instance if they were here: `sample.com/demo/aboutus?theme=theme1` then they would be sent here: `sample.com/demo/aboutus?theme=newtheme`

Comment: *I do not care if the page doesn't reload in fact I need it to reload* this doesn't seem to make sense; do you want it to reload or  not?

Answer (score 1):

A simple regex would do:

```
window.location = window.location.url.replace(/(\?|&)theme=[^&]+/, '$1theme=newtheme');
```

Answer (score -1):

Just make your anchor tag relative:

```
<a href="?theme=theme1">Theme 1</a>
<a href="?theme=theme2">Theme 2</a>
<a href="?theme=theme3">Theme 3</a>
```

the only downside is the current querystring will be completely replaced with the new one, if that is even an issue.

This can of course be done with javascript too:

```
window.location = "?theme=theme1";
//window.location = "?theme=theme2";
//window.location = "?theme=theme3";
```